# convert date format yywwd to dd-mm-yy

Tags: date, ms-access, format

In Access, I would like to convert a date column in format yywwd to dd-mm-yy. (weekday nr. 1 is monday, and years can only from 2000 and later, so e.g. today (monday 15-06-2020) would be 20251 what I would like to be converted to 15-06-2020.

I'm not much of a coder so honestly asside from messing with Datepart I have not tried a whole lot. Does anyone have suggestion?

It seems that the function 'GetDayFromWeekNumber' mentioned here [vba convert week number (and year) to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271678/vba-convert-week-number-and-year-to-date)  could work but how is this used in MSAccess?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: So this is a text type field?

Comment: Is the week part always 2 digits? The day part will be either 1 or 2 digits?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vba convert week number (and year) to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271678/vba-convert-week-number-and-year-to-date)

Comment: yes it's a text field (import from excel sheet). The week is indeed always 2 digits (01-53) and the day will be 1 to 7. (monday to sunday)

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that works in Excel to convert YYWWD to a date, this should be very similar if not identical to the code needed in Access. It is quite verbose so you could probably make it simpler, but at least the calculation steps are clearly set out.

The function assumes the ISO definition of week number - i.e. the first week of the year is the week in which the 4th of Jan falls. The first day of a week is Monday, the last day of a week is Sunday.

```
Function dateFromYYWWD(yywwd)
    Dim sYYWWD As String
    Dim sYYYY As String

    Dim ww As Integer
    Dim d As Integer

    Dim fourthOfJan As Date
    Dim fourthOfJanWeekday As Integer
    Dim week1StartDate As Date
    Dim targetWeekStartDate As Date

    Dim targetDate As Date

    ' Convert to string if not already
    sYYWWD = "" & yywwd

    ' Get the year in full
    sYYYY = "20" + Left(sYYWWD, 2)

    ' Get the week number and day in the week
    ww = CInt(Mid(sYYWWD, 3, 2))
    d = CInt(Right(sYYWWD, 1))

    ' Calculate the date of 4th Jan in the same year
    fourthOfJan = CDate(sYYYY & "-01-04")

    ' Get the day of week of the 4th Jan
    ' NOTE - CALCULATES MONDAY AS DAY 1 OF THE WEEK, SUNDAY AS DAY 7
    fourthOfJanWeekday = Weekday(fourthOfJan, vbMonday)

    ' Date of the first day of week #1 in the target year
    week1StartDate = fourthOfJan - fourthOfJanWeekday + 1

    ' First day of the target week
    targetWeekStartDate = week1StartDate + (ww - 1) * 7

    ' Target date
    targetDate = targetWeekStartDate + d - 1


    dateFromYYWWD = targetDate

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggest JohnRc, this also looks promising! I'll have to do some study myself about how to tinker this into Access. I'll let you know when i got it working!

Comment: I had a look at Access - looks like the function above can be lifted direct. You need to go into Database Tools > Visual Basic, then in the VB project window click on Insert > Module. Paste the code into the module, putting Public in front of the function so it reads `Public Function dateFromYYWWD(yywwd)`. Then I think you should just be able to call the function as `Module1.dateFromYYWWD( xx )`.  You could rename the module to something more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```
Public Function ConvertFromYYWWD(s) As Date
    Dim t&
    t = DateSerial(2000 + Mid(s, 1, 2), 1, 1) + 7 * (Mid(s, 3, 2) - 1)
    ConvertFromYYWWD = t - Weekday(t, vbMonday) + Mid(s, 5, 1)
End Function
```

Just place the above function in a code module in the database project.

You mentioned in the comments under your question that the week number is always two digits. I am assuming the the year number is likewise always two digits.

Answer (score -1):

The first task is to split the value:

```vb
YWDDate = 20251

Year = YWDDate \ 1000 + 2000
 2020 

Week = (YWDDate Mod 1000) \ 10
 25 

Weekday = YWDDate Mod 10
 1
```

Then, as this probably is ISO 8601 week numbering, the year is not the calendar year but the ISO 8601 year, which native VBA knows nothing about, thus a custom function is needed:

```vb
' First day of the week.
WeekStart = DateYearWeek(25, 2020, vbMonday)
' Requested day of week (which here is the same)
WeekDate = DateAdd("d", 1 - 1, WeekStart)
```

The function is not that convoluted:

```vb
' Returns the date of Monday for the ISO 8601 week of IsoYear and Week.
' Optionally, returns the date of any other weekday of that week.
'
' 2017-05-03. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateYearWeek( _
    ByVal IsoWeek As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal IsoYear As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal DayOfWeek As VbDayOfWeek = VbDayOfWeek.vbMonday) _
    As Date

    Dim WeekDate    As Date
    Dim ResultDate  As Date

    If IsoYear = 0 Then
        IsoYear = Year(Date)
    End If

    ' Validate parameters.
    If Not IsWeekday(DayOfWeek) Then
        ' Don't accept invalid values for DayOfWeek.
        Err.Raise DtError.dtInvalidProcedureCallOrArgument
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Not IsWeek(IsoWeek, IsoYear) Then
        ' A valid week number must be passed.
        Err.Raise DtError.dtInvalidProcedureCallOrArgument
        Exit Function
    End If

    WeekDate = DateAdd(IntervalSetting(dtWeek), IsoWeek - 1, DateFirstWeekYear(IsoYear))
    ResultDate = DateThisWeekPrimo(WeekDate, DayOfWeek)

    DateYearWeek = ResultDate

End Function
```

but - as you can see - it calls some helper functions, which again call other functions, which will be too much to post here.

I can upload it somewhere, if you feel this will provide a solution for you.

Comment: Hi Gustav,  well it sure seems like this is going somewhere but I problably first should get my fingers around the basics of how to use this VBA in Access. So many thanks so far and I'll get back to this perhaps when I have managed to get a simple thing going!

Comment: There is no simple work-around. On the hand, once held in a module, the code is simple to implement - as you can see.