# Convert week number and year to a date in Access-SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Microsoft Access, I **have a table** where number of hours worked per weekday are associated to a project number, ISO-week number and year. Simplified, it looks like this:

| ProjectID | WeekNumber | YearNumber | Monday | Tuesday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022 | 5 | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022 | 7 | 8 |

I am trying to set up a query where all weekday columns (monday to sunday) are "merged" into one column and the week and year numbers are converted to dates. It **should look like this**:

| ProjectID | Date | HoursPerDay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03.01.2022 | 5 |
| 1 | 04.01.2022 | 6 |
| 1 | 10.01.2022 | 7 |
| 1 | 11.01.2022 | 8 |

I managed to merge all weekday columns into one column using a UNION query:

```
SELECT ProjectID, WeekNumber, YearNumber, Monday As HoursPerDay FROM ProjectHours
UNION ALL
SELECT ProjectID, WeekNumber, YearNumber, Tuesday As HoursPerDay FROM ProjectHours;
```

The result looks like this:

| ProjectID | WeekNumber | YearNumber | HoursPerDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | 2022 | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022 | 8 |

But I am stuck **converting the iso-week and year number to a date**. Is this at all possible in Access-SQL?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37480952/12418842) on Stackoverflow and went through the [date/time functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/684295d0-97c2-443c-8e0a-8c6b635bec56#ID0EAABAAA=Date_time&ID0EBBD=Date_time) that Microsoft lists for Access but could not get it to work.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**: A community member has suggested a possible duplicate of this question, but I am looking for a solution that I can use in an Access-SQL query, so the suggested duplicate does not help me, as it suggests a VBA based solution.

Comment: @Austin No, it should be dd.mm.yyyy, so that I can use the query as a basis for several reports. So my strategy would be to get the date of the monday in a give week and add days for the tuesday, wednesday,... columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vba convert week number (and year) to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271678/vba-convert-week-number-and-year-to-date)

Comment: @June7 I think not. I am able to do that calculation in VBA (a loop through the recordset where I populate an empty table with the results would be my backup plan), but I would like to know if there is any chance to get this done using just Access-SQL, as it would likely be much faster.

Comment: You can't. Access SQL has no native date handling functions. And even if you could, it would be unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not so simple, as the ISO years rarely are in sync with calendar years.

But this function will do:

```vb
' Returns the date of Monday for the ISO 8601 week of IsoYear and Week.
' Optionally, returns the date of any other weekday of that week.
'
' 2017-05-03. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateYearWeek( _
    ByVal IsoWeek As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal IsoYear As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal DayOfWeek As VbDayOfWeek = VbDayOfWeek.vbMonday) _
    As Date
    
    Dim WeekDate    As Date
    Dim ResultDate  As Date
    
    If IsoYear = 0 Then
        IsoYear = Year(Date)
    End If
    
    ' Validate parameters.
    If Not IsWeekday(DayOfWeek) Then
        ' Don't accept invalid values for DayOfWeek.
        Err.Raise DtError.dtInvalidProcedureCallOrArgument
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Not IsWeek(IsoWeek, IsoYear) Then
        ' A valid week number must be passed.
        Err.Raise DtError.dtInvalidProcedureCallOrArgument
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    WeekDate = DateAdd(IntervalSetting(dtWeek), IsoWeek - 1, DateFirstWeekYear(IsoYear))
    ResultDate = DateThisWeekPrimo(WeekDate, DayOfWeek)
    
    DateYearWeek = ResultDate

End Function
```

However, it uses a series of supporting functions, like:

```vb
' Returns the primo date of the week of the date passed.
'
' 2016-01-13. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateThisWeekPrimo( _
    ByVal DateThisWeek As Date, _
    Optional ByVal FirstDayOfWeek As VbDayOfWeek = vbSunday) _
    As Date

    Dim Interval    As String
    Dim Number      As Double
    Dim ResultDate  As Date
    
    Number = 0
    Interval = IntervalSetting(DtInterval.dtWeek)
    
    ResultDate = DateIntervalPrimo(Interval, Number, DateThisWeek, FirstDayOfWeek)
    
    DateThisWeekPrimo = ResultDate
    
End Function
```

and several more - way too much to post here.

So, please refer to my project at **GitHub**, [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date), for the modules holding the full code.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer. First of all, I have to admit, that I work 98,5% of my time with Excel and VBA and normally not with Access. I was not aware that user defined functions where possible in Access-SQL-queries, but I just tested that one with a very simple example and it seems to work, so I really learned something new today. With that, I do not think I will need any native date handling functions anyway.

Comment: Yes, I believe it will fit. It runs in about 20µs.

Comment: Extremely helpful. TYSM!